# Yii url from the start localhost or www

Tags: url, yii, localhost

I need a url from the very start like
 `localhost/myApp/index.php?r=controller/action/id` 
when I am on localhost and
 `www.sitename.com/index.php?r=controller/action/id`.
 Later on I would change the format to make it SEO friendly but right now Yii::app()->baseUrl gives just `myApp/` 
What is the function I can use in Yii to make the url from the base. Apparently I have used it. But can't find it in the [API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/) now.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use `Yii::app()->baseUrl`? So you need the localhost part to be prepended to `Yii::app()->baseUrl`?

Comment: prepend/append functions is not a good code. So was looking for something inbuilt. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I was more just asking what you needing this for, out of interest? (As in why you can't use `baseUrl`)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('site/index');
```

from the [API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#createAbsoluteUrl-detail) itself. This would give you the path from the very base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below:

```
Yii::app()->getRequest()->getBaseUrl(true)
```